# how to Select rows in table where id is first grup by other id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table new_table

```
ID       PROC_ID       STAFF_ID
1          558           4141
2          558           601
3          558           556
-------------------------------
4          602           601
5          602           795
-------------------------------
6          634           601
7          634           195
8          634           295
-------------------------------
9          705           601
10         705           788
-------------------------------
11         716           458
12         716           601
...        ...           ...
n          1890          4141
```

when I can select proc_id from new_table where staff_id = 601 get result. for example

```
proc_id
602
634
705
```

where staff_id is first order_by id

Comment: could you explain it more detailed?

Comment: @ArunVinoth - The OP explained pretty clearly (in my opinion). Take 558 for example. Which is the lowest ID? It is ID = 1. What is the STAFF_ID for that ID? Answer: 4141 (not 601!) Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select proc_id
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by proc_id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and staff_id = 601;
```

Another fun method uses aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select proc_id
from t
group by proc_id
having min(id) = min(case when staff_id = 601 then id end);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard aggregate query with a `having` clause. The condition in the `having` clause uses the `first/last` function (google Oracle documentation if you are not familiar with this aggregate function).

```
with
     inputs ( id, proc_id, staff_id ) as (
       select  1,  558, 4141 from dual union all
       select  2,  558,  601 from dual union all
       select  3,  558,  556 from dual union all
       select  4,  602,  601 from dual union all
       select  5,  602,  795 from dual union all
       select  6,  634,  601 from dual union all
       select  7,  634,  195 from dual union all
       select  8,  634,  295 from dual union all
       select  9,  705,  601 from dual union all
       select 10,  705,  788 from dual union all
       select 11,  716,  458 from dual union all
       select 12,  716,  601 from dual union all
       select 99, 1890, 4141 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated data (for testing purposes only, not part of the query).
-- Solution begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   proc_id
from     inputs
group by proc_id
having   min(staff_id) keep (dense_rank first order by id) = 601
;

PROC_ID
-------
602
634
705
```